# How to quickly search through word docs saved in database

Tags: php, sql, .net, lucene, lucene.net

For a project I am required to allow users to upload MS WORD docs (uploading either via web or desktop program)

Other users should be able to quickly search through the docs (can be thousands of uploaded docs) and list all docs that contain the searched word or phrase.

What will be the best way to handle this ?

I am thinking it is better to save the word docs into the database and allow full text search . Will full text search work properly on files that are saved into blobs fields?Is this the best option ?

Please suggest

Comment: are you talking about doc files or docx files?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt say its the best option.
Use Solr (that uses Lucene) to properly index documents.
Then use that index for searching. Solr has well documented search api:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Overview+of+Searching+in+Solr